# How to rename multiple files depending on its parent directories name in linux?

Tags: command-line, rename

I have a main directory `bp` and it has many sub-directories `bp01`, `bp02`, `bp04`. In each directory it has a file and the name of each file is randomly but start with co. I want to change each file name the same as its parent directory.

The following is the structure of my folder:

[image]

I want it look like this:

[image]

I am green hand in Linux,hope some one can help me. Thank you:)

Comment: For future please don't post images of text. Output of GUI terminal can easily be copied via Ctr + Shift  + C in most modern terminals

Comment: Thank you for the kind suggestion and explanation Sergiy:)))

Answer (score 1):

maybe this can help you:

```
cd bp
for subdir in ./*; do mv -v ./"$subdir"/*.nii ./"$subdir"/"$subdir".nii; done;
```

Comment: I got the same problem once, and thanks to quick search on google I found this tip on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306117/rename-files-in-multiple-directories-to-the-name-of-the-directory#)

Comment: Hi :) Welcome to AskUbuntu. You can edit your question to include additional details such as those in your comment. I'll process this editr for you this time as an example. Also, well done on the formatting!

Comment: Thank you for your kind help:))) I will study further.